# Reset Lucee Server admin password

Tags: lucee

I recently installed Lucee and cannot remember the password I set for the server admin (luceee/admin/server.cfm).

How do I go about resetting the server admin password?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. In the server config file (*lib/ext/lucee-server/context/lucee-server.xml*), remove the attributes `hspw` and `salt` from the `cfLuceeConfiguration` tag
2. Restart Lucee

Comment: I can confirm this still works in Jan 2023 with 5.3.10.97. And if you don't find the path mentioned here, note that different ways of installing Lucee can lead to files/folders being in different places than someone (or some docs) may say (not just the top-level folder but even lower-level ones). For example, those who run the Lucee installer on Windows may find the location could be C:\lucee\tomcat\lucee-server\context\lucee-server.xml (no "lib/ext"). If you're stuck, just search for wherever you may have that lucee-server.xml file. There should be only one in any given Lucee implementation.