# Confusion resetting Lucee admin password

Tags: passwords, lucee

I have forgotten the server password for my Lucee installation.  There are instructions on stack overflow here: [Reset Lucee Server admin password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587623/reset-lucee-server-admin-password).  It involves removing two lines from the Lucee server context configuration file and restarting Lucee.

I already have two datasources and I don't want to lose them.  If I remove these two lines from the config file, and restart Lucee I presume that somewhere I have to reset the server password.

1. How do you do that?
2. Will that invalidate my current datasources?
3. And if so can I re-estabish them using the new password?

Answer (score 1):

1. After editing the `lucee-server.xml` file and restarting Lucee
   simply go to the server admin login page where you will be prompted
   to set a new password.
2. No, your datasources and other settings won't have been affected.

Although this should work fine, I would make a copy of the `lucee-server.xml` file before you edit it just in case.

Comment: Well, I did everything, and my old datasource seems to be fine as you said.  However, I still cannot set up a new datasource -- it rejects the new password I created.  I set it up with "root" as the user.  Do you have any thoughts about what I should do now?

Comment: The password for accessing the Lucee admin is completely unconnected to any datasource logins. You'll need whatever password is required for the database you're trying to use.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Your help much appreciated.  I could not find any documentation that said this simple thing.